# Does JParsec have an `until' combinator?

Tags: jparsec

An `until' combinator consumes input until the given parser has been satisfied.

I googled and gave a glimpse of the source of the Parser class, didn't find one. I think this combinator is common in every parser combinator framework in other languages.

Comment: I think you might want to add a broader tag to this question to get more people seeing it. I don't know which tag would be the most appropriate though. I suspect most `[java]` people haven't used `JParsec`, but perhaps `[haskell]` will work?

Comment: Alright, I'm sure there's no until combinator or similar ones. I have generated a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the PR :-) It is merged, so now *there is* an `until` combinator for parsec.